# Extract latest entry from a model in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

Let's say I have the following Django model:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    instrument = models.ForeignKey('Instrument')
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I extract the entry with the newest date for each Instrument ?

Comment: Why don't you just add a "date" property to the Instrument model?

Comment: I had it like that, but it seemed like redundant information. I see now that probably it was better like this than to struggle ... :(

Comment: The further your project advances, the more properties you'll be adding to your models :)

Comment: Actually, it would make more sense to have the date put on the Instrument model instead of the Info model since instrument is required. That way you can access it like info.instrument.date and the instrument could still access it fairly easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Instrument.objects.all().annotate(max_date=models.Max("info__date"))
```

It will return a list of all instruments and each intrument will have additional attribute `max_date` which contains the latest date for this instrument.

Comment: It's close, but not ther yet. I decided I'll quit this approch, and go with the redundant way: store the date also in the Instrument. The idea is that in the list from your example, an instrument can appear multiple times. Anyway, I'll give you the correct answer, cause I'm tired of this approach X(

Comment: Actually each Instrument appears only once in this list.

Comment: Aaaa! Ok! Now I see... I used Info.objects instead of Instrument.objects. This looks like it may work. I'll give it a try later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latest `Info` entry for each instrument, you could do something like this:

```
latest_notes = []
for instrument in Instrument.objects.all():
    latest_note = instrument.info_set.order_by('-date')[0]
    latest_notes.append(latest_note)
```

That may or may not be feasible depending on how many `Instrument` records you have.

Comment: An instrument can appear multiple time in the Info model, and I need a list of all Intruments, not just one.

Comment: Long story short: I need a list with the latest instruments, not to check for each one individually

Comment: `info_set` will give you all of the `Info` objects that point to a given `Instrument` object.

Comment: @Nicolae Surdu: I updated my answer, although I'm not sure I understand what you want. Your question says you want to do something "for each instrument", but your comment suggests otherwise.

Comment: Your latest edit is close enough (as far as I got), but it may contain an instrument multiple times. What I need is each Instrument to appear just once, and be the one with the latest date

Comment: @Nicolae Surdu: Do you want the latest instrument, or the latest info for each instrument? I don't understand your comment: "Your latest edit is close enough (as far as I got), but it may contain an instrument multiple times.", as my line of code only grabs a single `Info` object (the latest one) and its associated `Instrument`, so there's only one `Instrument` returned and thus it appears only once.

Comment: How can I extract the entry with the newest date for EACH Instrument ? What you wrote there will extract the latest Instrument from all entries.

Comment: I was refering to this Info.objects.order_by('-date') when I said it may contain an instrument multiple times.

Comment: @Nicolae Surdu: I updated my answer with a possible solution, but it may not be feasible for very large datasets.